# how to split the data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I wanted to split the movie production company name from the data ..Need to extract company name .

```
df['production_companies'].head(20)

0     [{'name': 'Pixar Animation Studios', 'id': 3}]
1     [{'name': 'TriStar Pictures', 'id': 559}, {'na...
3     [{'name': 'Twentieth Century Fox Film Corporat...
4     [{'name': 'Sandollar Productions', 'id': 5842}...
5     [{'name': 'Regency Enterprises', 'id': 508}, {...
8     [{'name': 'Universal Pictures', 'id': 33}, {'n...
9     [{'name': 'United Artists', 'id': 60}, {'name'...
10    [{'name': 'Columbia Pictures', 'id': 5}, {'nam...
12    [{'name': 'Universal Pictures', 'id': 33}, {'n...
13    [{'name': 'Hollywood Pictures', 'id': 915}, {'...
14    [{'name': 'Le Studio Canal+', 'id': 183}, {'na...
15    [{'name': 'Universal Pictures', 'id': 33}, {'n...
16    [{'name': 'Columbia Pictures Corporation', 'id...
17    [{'name': 'Miramax Films', 'id': 14}, {'name':...
18    [{'name': 'O Entertainment', 'id': 5682}, {'na...
19             [{'name': 'Columbia Pictures', 'id': 5}]
20    [{'name': 'Jersey Films', 'id': 216}, {'name':...
22    [{'name': 'Silver Pictures', 'id': 1885}, {'na...
24    [{'name': 'United Artists', 'id': 60}, {'name'...
26              [{'name': 'New Line Cinema', 'id': 12}]
Name: production_companies, dtype: object
```

Comment: df['production_companies'] = df['production_companies'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
df['production_companies'] = df['production_companies'].fillna("[]").apply(lambda x: [i['name'] for i in x] if isinstance(x, list) else [])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `explode()` and then get the individual **name** from the dictionary and reset the index **inplace**

```
df['name']=df['production_companies'].explode().apply(lambda x:x['name']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Could you please try it once after the edit. I've used this sample dataframe df=pd.DataFrame({'production_companies':[[{'name':'ABC','id':1}],[{'name':'CDE','id':2},{'name':'DEF','id':3}],[{'name':'FDE','id':4}]]}) and it works fine

Comment: okay let me see ur sample dataframe .

Comment: But i still get error in my cases .

Answer (score 2):

We can do `explode`

```
s = df['production_companies'].explode()
namedata = pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(),index=s.index)
```

Comment: I need to split it too.